# Three ways to find the normal of a hyperboloid?

Tags: calculus, vectors, surfaces

In the hyperboloid $x^2 + y^2 − z^2 = 4$, where $z \ge 0$, I have found three ways to get the normal vector, but my problem is they do not seem equivalent.

The first is as I have been taught that you can find the gradient of the function, and that will be the normal:
$$\langle 2x,2y,-2z \rangle$$

The unit normal should be

$$\langle {2x\over \sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4z^2} },{2y\over \sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4z^2}},{-2z\over \sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4z^2}} \rangle$$
$$=\langle {2x\over \sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4(x^2+y^2-4)} },{2y\over \sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4(x^2+y^2-4)}},{-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4}\over \sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4(x^2+y^2-4)}} \rangle$$
$$=\langle {2x\over 2\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2-4} },{2y\over 2\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2-4}},{-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4}\over 2\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2-4}} \rangle$$

A second way would be to rewrite the hyperboloid as $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4}$
and then use the identity that the normal is $\langle f_x,f_y,-1 \rangle$
Then the normal is $$\langle {x\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2-4} },{y\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2-4}},-1 \rangle$$

The unit normal is then

$$\langle {x \sqrt{x^2+y^2-4} \over 2x^2+2y^2-4 },{y  \sqrt{x^2+y^2-4} \over 2x^2+2y^2-4},-\big( {x^2+y^2-4\over 2x^2+2y^2-4} \big) \rangle$$

The third is to use the parametrization $x=r \cos t, y=r\sin t ,z= r^2$. Then the normal is given by  $$r_r \times r_t= \langle -2r^2\cos t, -2r^2\sin t, r \rangle$$

The unit normal should be

$$\langle {-2r\cos t\over \sqrt{4r^2+1}}, {-2r\sin t \over \sqrt{4r^2+1}}, {1\over \sqrt{4r^2+1}} \rangle$$

However, it does not seem that these are equivalent, so which ones are incorrect and why?

Comment: Ignoring normalization ...Your first vector, divided-through by $2$, is $(x,y,-z)$. Your second, multiplied-through by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4}$, is $(x,y,-\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4}) = (x,y,-z)$. So, those are equivalent. Your third vector is problematic, which isn't surprising, since your parameterization doesn't satisfy the surface's equation. :)

Comment: Oh, why does it not? I mean what would be the proper parametrization? Is it that I ignored the 4?

Comment: Substituting your $x$, $y$, $z$ parameterizations into the surface's equation gives $$r^2\cos^2t+r^2\sin^2t-(r^2)^2=4 \quad\to\quad r^2-r^4=4$$ which, for arbitrary values of $r$, is generally not a valid relation.

Comment: So what is the proper parametrization? I am having difficulty coming up with it.

Comment: There are many. One would be $$x=r\cos t \qquad y=r\sin t \qquad z = \sqrt{r^2-4}$$

Comment: Thanks, you made my day. I was literally spending many hours on many problems confused about this point!

Comment: Glad to help. Since we've identified the source of your problem, I'll convert my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring normalization ...

- Your first vector, divided-through by $2$, is $(x,y,−z)$.
- Your second vector, multiplied-through by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2−4}$, is $(x,y,−\sqrt{x^2+y^2−4})=(x,y,−z)$

So, those vectors are equivalent.

Your third vector is problematic, which isn't surprising, since your parameterization doesn't satisfy the surface's equation:

$$(r\cos t)^2 + ( r\sin t)^2 - ( r^2 )^2 = 4 \quad\to\quad r^2\cos^2t+r^2\sin^2t-r^4=4\quad\to\quad r^2-r^4=4$$ 
which, for arbitrary $r$, generally isn't true.

One correct parameterization would be

$$x = r \cos t \qquad y = r \sin t \qquad z = \sqrt{r^2-4}$$

(Verifying that this satisfies the surface's equation is left as an exercise to the reader.)

If you don't care for the square root, you can make the substitution $r=2\sec s$, so that the parameterization becomes
$$x = 2\sec s \cos t \qquad y = 2 \sec s \sin t \qquad z = \sqrt{4\sec^2s-4}=\sqrt{4\tan^2s}=2\tan s$$

In the latter case, 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}(x,y,z) \times \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x,y,z) &= ( 2 \sec s \tan s \cos t, 2 \sec s \tan s \sin t, 2 \sec^2 s ) \tag{1}\\
&\quad\times (-2 \sec s \sin t, 2 \sec s \cos t, 0) \\[4pt]
&\propto ( \sin s \cos t, \sin s \sin t, 1 ) \times (-\sin t, \cos t, 0) \tag{2}\\[4pt]
&= (-\cos t, -\sin t, \sin s) \tag{3}\\
&\propto (2\sec s\cos t, 2\sec s\sin t, -2\tan s) \tag{4}\\
&=(x,y,-z) \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
In $(3)$, I scaled the vectors by dividing-through by $2\sec^2s$ and $2\sec s$, respectively, to simplify the calculation of their cross-product. In $(4)$, I multiplied-through by $-2\sec s$ to make the equivalence with $(x,y,-z)$ apparent.

Comment: I have a question though, why do I get different magnitudes with my first and second approach (after taking out the 2)? First is $||\mathbf n||=\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2-4}$, second is  $||\mathbf n||={\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2-4}\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2-4} }$. Which is the "correct" magnitude, for example if I was trying to find the surface integral?

Comment: That's an *excellent* question, and you should ask it separately to get proper responses. I'll just say here that there is no "correct" magnitude, as there is no "correct" parameterization. Hand-waving furiously: the integrals *just work*. Indeed, you've already seen them do so. Consider, for instance, a $u$-substitution with the old-fashioned integral, $\int_a^b f(x)dx$; this amounts to a re-parameterization of $f(x)$, but the adjustments required to convert $dx$ to $du$ (and also $x$-limits of integration to $u$-limits) guarantee that the result comes out the same.

Comment: Indeed I did basically ask this question just yesterday (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231290/surface-integral-of-hyperboloid-using-polar-coordinates-fails), and the answer given in the comments is that the correct magnitude in that case is the second, not the first. I checked it and it does seem to be true, I just don't really understand why.

Comment: Ah ... Good for you. :)  I don't have time right now, but if someone doesn't give you an answer you can live with soon-ish, then I'll see what I can do.